# Is it possible to alter the message headers of an AMQPMessage in a PHP consumer?

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, message-queue, php-amqplib

I am using Symfony 2 and the videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle to push messages to a queue post event-firing in Symfony.

The queue itself is all working fine and the messages are looking perfect on the queue.

I'm aware that it's not possible to change the *content* of a message in the AMQP spec, but is it possible to add or alter message *headers* at all, and if so, would anyone know how that's accomplished please?

Essentially, I'm attempting to gracefully implement a 'max retries' concept. Previously I've 'acked' the message and queued up an identical one to the same queue, only with a now-incremented '# of attempts' field. This is fine, and it works, but it feels very messy, which is what inspired the question.

TL;DR is there **any** way of updating a message before requeueing, and are headers the best way to go about it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you use basic.reject and similar methods, then you can't modify headers.

Comment: Thanks @old_sound - guess I'll resort to queueing up an identical message with the incremented attempt number. Real shame that AMQP doesn't support this natively as it's a much more controlled way of limiting retries than a TTL. Thanks again though!